# starting out with C++, password verifier

Tags: c++

I have been working on this problem for countless hours and I can not find what the problem is.  I changed and tested every part of the problem and always get bizarre and erroneous results.  I am starting to think that maybe my compiler is malfunctioning.

This is what i am trying to do:
Develop a program that prompts for a password and the program checks that the following conditions are met.

minimum of 6 characters long.

contain at least one uppercase letter.

contain at least one lowercase letter.

contain at least one digit.

if the entered password does not meet the criteria then the program should display why and prompt for re-entry.  if the password is good then it displays a message and ends the program.  Please help!

NOTE: this is a console 32 program.

```c
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include "ctype.h"
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
bool lengthTest(char *);
bool lowCaseTest(char []);
bool upCaseTest(char []);
bool digitTest(char []);
const int SIZE = 20;

int main()
{
    // Buffer to hold the string.
    char password[SIZE];
    int sumofbool;
    // Program Intro Display
    cout << "----PASSWORD VERIFIER PROGRAM----\n\n";
    cout << "Enter a password that meets the following criteria:\n"
    << "-Minimum of 6 characters in length.\n"
    << "-Contains at least one uppercase and one lowercase letter.\n"
    << "-Contains at least one digit.\n\n";
    cout << "->";
    // Get input from user.
    cin.getline(password, SIZE);

    sumofbool = lengthTest(password) + lowCaseTest(password) + upCaseTest(password)
    + digitTest(password);
    // if 1 or more of the 4 functions is not true, display why and prompt for re-entry.
    while (sumofbool < 4)
    {
        if (!lengthTest(password))
        cout << "Error, password must be at least 6 characters long.\n";

        if (!upCaseTest(password))
        cout << "Error, password must contain at least one upper case letter.\n";

        if (!lowCaseTest(password))
        cout << "Error, password must contain at least one lower case letter.\n";

        if (!digitTest(password))
        cout << "Error, password must contain at least one digit.\n";

        cout << "Please re-enter password: ";
        // prompt for re-entry and call functions to test input.
        cin.getline(password, SIZE);
        sumofbool = lengthTest(password) + lowCaseTest(password) + upCaseTest(password);
        + digitTest(password);
    }
    // if conditions for password are met, display message.
    cout << "\nYou entered a valid password.\n\n";

    return 0;
}

//*********LENGTH TEST FUNCTION***********
bool lengthTest(char *str)
{
    int numChar = 0;
    bool validlength = false;
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; cnt++)
    {
        while (*str != 0)
        str++, numChar++;
    }
    if (numChar >= 6)
    validlength = true;

    return validlength;

}
//*********LOWERCASE LETTER TEST FUNCTION*********
bool lowCaseTest(char pass[])
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; cnt++)
    {
        if (islower(pass[cnt]))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//********CAPITAL LETTER TEST FUNCTION*********
bool upCaseTest(char pass[])
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 20; cnt++)
    {
        if (isupper(pass[cnt]))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//**********DIGIT TEST FUNCTION************
bool digitTest(char pass[])
{
    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 20; cnt++)
    {
        if (isdigit(pass[cnt]))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *I am starting to think that maybe my compiler is malfunctioning.*   Almost always a sign that you are malfunctioning and it is time to take a walk or get some sleep.

Comment: Give the example to which it is failing. It would be then easy to reverse engineer.

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to with the fact that the program is testing SIZE characters in every string passed in with no guarantee that the string is SIZE characters long.  This should really stop testing once a NULL character is reached, otherwise I would imagine you should expect undefined behavior.

Comment: When starting out in a new programming language, "the compiler might be broken" is pretty much guaranteed to be the wrong conclusion. In fact, even if you had been using it for 20 years, it should still be the last theory on a very long checklist.

Comment: On another note, are you writing this code to learn programming, or to learn C++? I ask because the `lengthTest` function is unnecessary; `lengthTest(password)` could be replaced by `strlen(password) >= 6`, and similar simplifications are available for the other tests. Also, you should read into a `std::string`, not a `char[SIZE]`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra semicolon in the lines

```
sumofbool = lengthTest(password) + lowCaseTest(password) + upCaseTest(password);
+ digitTest(password);
```

(Wow, that took a while to spot.) Fixing this should resolve the length issues.

I also think the lines:

```
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < SIZE; cnt++)
{
    while (*str != 0)
    str++, numChar++;
}
```

can be shortened to just

```
while (*str != 0)
str++, numChar++;
```

, although this won't change the functionality. The former just counts the length, then for `SIZE - 1` iterations just does nothing.

Also, as BenTrofatter mentioned in the comments, you're checking `SIZE` amount of characters every time you test the string. If the string is shorter than `SIZE`, you don't know what memory you're accessing after the string length.

Since you tagged this as C++, I'd say go with C++ strings as MarceloCantos mentioned. They're easier to work with in general, from passing parameters to accessing substrings.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't try to sum boolean values
2. replace whatever you have in `lengthTest()` with simple call to `strlen(str)`
3. everywhere you access a string in a loop, use `strlen()` as the loop terminator condition, not any hardcoded value you have there right now
4. don't use `while (*str != 0) str++` -- this is gonna bite you in the ass every time with running away pointers and memory corruption issues
5. use variables i, j, k in the loops -- this is standard for C/C++

also, i would definitely replace the multiple runs over the same string with a single run like this:

```
bool has_uppers = false, has_lowers = false, has_digits = false;

int length = strlen(password);
for( int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    char ch = password[i];
    has_uppers |= isupper(ch);
    has_lowers |= islower(ch);
    has_digits |= isdigit(ch);
}
```